# JavaScript internationalization with django

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization

I've got a script.js file which is located in common/static/js/ directory. Common is a directory, not an application and I need to translate messages inside script into other languages. How should I configure my django project? Basic instructions please, because I'm dumm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple approach is to set your translatable values at the template level for your JavaScript functions/classes to pick up:

var my_name= '{% trans my_name %}';

But Django does have [JavaScript internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code).

Comment: Please fix the link, is not working now, i suggest link for django 1.8: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code

Another similar aproach would be to create an object called "RESOURCE" and store there every string instead of creating a variable for every string.